# Аппаратный + программный ШИМ в AVR

Tags: avr, atmel-studio

Возможно ли реализовать аппаратный ШИМ с программной корректировкой коэффициента заполнения ?
Использую МК attiny85, а в нем таймер 0, настроенный для ШИМ в режиме fast PWM, и сравниваю через регистр OCR0A. Все работает, но корректировке коэфф. заполнения на 1 (при изменении значения в OCR0A), очень сильно(моем случае) меняется потребляемая мощность. Необходимо регулировать более плавно по 0,1-0,5 от возможного шага.
Идея такова, чтобы импульс от аппаратного ШИМа состоялся, потом перейти к той части кода, в которой на ножке ШИМа вновь включить лог 1 на заданное время корректировки (забить длительность NOP-ами). После установить лог 0.

Пробовал переходить в прерывание по совпадению с OCR0A и проделать такой трюк, но результата негативный.

При написании программы использую AtmelStudio и пишу на С.

```
// set non-inverting mode
TCCR0A |= (1<<COM0A1) | (0<<COM0A0);
// set fast PWM Mode
TCCR0A |= (1<<WGM01) | (1<<WGM00);

// set prescaler to 1024 and starts PWM
TCCR0B |= (0<<CS02) | (1<<CS01) | (0<<CS00);
```

Answer (score 0):

В общем случае, ответ - **нет**: нельзя удлинить длительность аппаратно-генерируемого ШИМ импульса на дробное часло тактов таймера.

У вас выбран прескалер 1 к 8 (несмотря на сбивающий с толку комментарий про 1024), значит, вы хотите генерировать импульс с точностью 1-4 такта процессора.

Правильным решением, в вашем случае, было бы взять микроконтроллер с ШИМ-выходом от 16-битного таймера, и использовать его с меньшим прескаллером.

Поскольку инструкции процессор выполняет от 1 до 3 тактов, значит задержка запуска обработчика прерывания просто архитектурно будет варьироваться до 2 тактов. Если же в основном теле программы встречаются блоки, блокирующие прерывания, или, ещё хуже, есть обработчики других прерываний, то задержка будет ещё больше.

С использованием 8-битного таймера возможным вариантом решения проблемы явилось бы чисто программная генерация импульсов. Если таймер работает с прескалером 1 к 1, то после входа в прерывание, ориентируясь на TCNT0 можно написать ассемблерный код так, чтобы он задержал выполнение с точностью до такта. Таким образом, вызывая заранее вызывая обработчки прерывания с таким выравнивающим кодом можно точно подобрать моменты включения и выключения импульсов. Разумеется нужно чётко следить за тем в каких циклах таймера разрешаются прерывания, и что не будет лишнего или пропущенного срабатывания прерывания в очередном цикле. Плюс нужно особо обрабатывать моменты для слишком коротких импульсов.

Но, как мне кажется, лучше рассмотреть вариант использования другого МК, либо пересмотреть схематическое решение.